# Can't push in GIT, but rebase up-to-date

Tags: git

Can anyone explain the state of my repository?  I can't push because there are changes on the server I don't have, but I can't rebase because git tells me there are no new changes.

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git push origin master
To git@github.com:asdf.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:asdf.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git fetch origin master
From github.com:knowitall/nlptools
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git rebase origin master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
Current branch master is up to date.

$ git pull origin master
```

The merge that it proposes is empty.

```
Merge branch 'master' of github.com:knowitall/nlptools

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
# 
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

If I create a branch, reset with origin/master, and then merge the branch, I *still* can't push.

```
$ git checkout -b backup
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch origin master
$ git reset origin/master --hard
$ git merge backup
$ git push origin master
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Now if I `reset` and `pull`, I see a new commit.  Why didn't `fetch origin master` find this new commit in the first place?  How can I make sure my repositories representation of origin is up to date?  It seems that I need to have a successful pull in order to have the origin up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in improper `git fetch` usage: `git fetch origin master` reads `master` as a refspec and does not behave like a regular fetch. More specifically, it just makes `FETCH_HEAD` to point on the remote `master`.

When `fetch` is used without refspec, it uses `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` as a default which updates all the refs `origin/*`.

Try `git fetch origin` or `git fetch` instead.

Here is a good doc about it for more details: https://git-scm.com/book/th/ch9-5.html

Answer (score 1):

When you `checkout -b`, you finish on the new branch. So you reset and merge onto backup already. Try it this way:

```
$ git branch backup
$ git fetch origin master
$ git reset origin/master --hard
$ git merge backup
$ git push origin master
```

If you're on Windows, look out [`posh-git`](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) to get visual feedback of your state on your command line (with powershell).

If you're on Mac or Linux, then checkout some `dot-files` repo on github to get similar functionnality.

Comment: What do you mean by "finish on the new branch"?

Comment: When you checkout you change branch. In your sample code, you didn't switch back to master afterward.